# Unique visitor counting in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, architecture

I'd like to do visitor tracking similar to how stackoverflow does it..

By reading through numerous posts, I've figured out some details already:

- Count only 1 IP hit per 15 minutes (if anonymous)
- Count only 1 unique user-Login (per day?)

Now that leaves the question of the real implementation..

Should I log the two factors live into a table (and increase count)

| IP | timestamp | pageurl |

Or do the counting AFTERWARDS (e.g. using IIS log files - which don't include the user, right?

I know there're some similar posts outside, but NONE really has a great solution in my opinion yet..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can discuss business logic of yours. Its up to you how you want it to be. I'd say, define what you call "unique user" and build your algorithm around it.

With regards to your question here, you will get a lot of opinions, but there's no right answer to your question.

*My opinion*: I would go with the table, combination of registered users and IP tracking for anonymous ones, so option one from your list.

For what its worth - that's is my take on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a table. Add user column to track if its a logged in user or anon. 
Unless you want to keep history, I would suggest flushing out the table at the end of the day to keep your searches fast.